# Make a <div> square when there is a dynamically changing width based on percentage

Tags: html, css, grid-layout, dimensions, aspect-ratio

I am working on a web app that will generate an NxN grid based on the user's selection of N. I want the total width of the grid to be relative (ie 100% of the available space) so that users can print on various paper sizes.

I can easily calculate the width of the squares in the grid by % (ie: 100%/N), but I am having issues calculating the height. The height of a web page is always going to be infinite unless I artificially limit it which, like I said, I don't want to do.

How can I make **the squares in my grid be square** versus rectangular when the height and width constraints of my grid are dynamic and not square?

Comment: The *real* problem is not the size of the squares: that is simply (height/n).  The problem is setting the total height of the grid to the same as it's width.  It's tricky, without either making some fixed-size assumptions, or using some form of scripting.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is un-tested, I do not know of how to do this in CSS only, I would use jQuery.

```
$('div').height($('div').width());
```

Comment: I didn't know JQuery at the time but once I learned it, this was easy enough. Thanks!

Comment: this will fail if the page get resized.

Answer (score 60):

There are 3 main techniques to keep the aspect ratio of a responsive element.
The first one is by far the best and will work for a variety of use cases : the `aspect-ratio` CSS property. The 2 others may suit other use cases : using padding or vw units :
*(for a complete solution for a responsive grid of squares, you can [see this  answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20457076/1811992))*

### The aspect-ratio property

This specifies directly the aspect ratio of and element. It can be based on the width or height of the element. ([see MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/aspect-ratio))
Here is an example :

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

div {
  width: 23%;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
  background: gold;
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

### Using vw units

You can use `vw` units to make your elements square and responsive ([viewport units on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#Viewport-percentage_lengths)).
`1vw = 1% of viewport width` so you can set the height of the elements according to the **width of the viewport** (or height with `vh` units).
Example with a 4x4 grid :

```css
body{
  margin:0;
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  justify-content:space-around;
}

div{
    width:23vw; height:23vw;
    margin:1vw 0;
    background:gold;  
}
```

```html
<div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
```

*The same behaviour can be achieved sizing the element according to the viewport height using `vh` units.*

---

### Using padding

Padding is calculated according to the container's width so you can use it to set the height of block according to its width.
Example with a 4x4 grid :

```css
.wrap {
    width:80%;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.wrap div {
    width:23%;
    padding-bottom:23%;
    margin:1%;
    float:left;
    background:gold;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is fine as long as you realise that vw and vh are relative to the size of the viewport, not any given container (unfortunately)

Comment: @frumbert I edited my answer with a solution based on the width of the container ("Padding technique")

Comment: that's an awesome hack! programmers for the win!!

Answer (score 28):

To make a div a square is pretty easy with CSS. You set a width, let's say 50%. Then you add a padding-bottom of the same value:

```
div {
width: 50%;
padding-bottom: 50%;
}
```

and it will stay square whenever you resize the window.

.

.

You can do this with any side ratio you want, if you want the box to be 16:9 you calculate:

9/16= 0.56

which you then multiply by the width of your element (in this case 50%(=0.5)), so:

9/16*0.5= 0.28 = 28%

Comment: I was looking for a pure css way to do this, thank you!

Comment: Don't work in Edge. :/ https://jsfiddle.net/836popre/3/

Comment: Beautiful solution, needs to be the answer.

Comment: FYI,  I used this solution to maintain a dynamic perfect circle, but I needed to explicitly set `height: 0` for it to work at all.

Comment: Unfortunately this seems to break when **max-width** is set, ie `max-width: 200px;`;

Comment: Great answer, can you explain how the padding-bottom makes the height equals to the width?

Answer (score -3):

The above solution doesn't preserve area - this one is better

```
        //@param {jQuery} div 
        function makeSquare(div){
            //make it square !
            var oldDimens = {
                h : div.height(),
                w : div.width()
            };
            var area = oldDimens.h * oldDimens.w;
            var l = Math.sqrt(area);
            div.height(l).width(l);
        }
```

Comment: I don't believe preserving area is relevant. The OP is wanting to no how to make an element square based on its width. Changing this width is kind of defeating the purpose. -1