# Jquery - Change div Height Based on Width

Tags: jquery, function, width

If i have, a class with width: 20%, how to create a jquery function to change the class height to the same width of the class but in pixels?

Comment: search before posting 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062811/height-div-based-on-percentage-based-width

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2648733/make-a-div-square-when-there-is-a-dynamically-changing-width-based-on-percenta

Answer (score 0):

Working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sarathsprakash/5bKdv/)**

Try this

```
 var pixels = parentWidth*(percent/100);
```