# CSS height equals by related width

Tags: html, css

In this case, I have a css like this:

```
.w{
    width:80%;
    display:block;
}

.d{
    width:14%;
    display:inline-block
}
```

and it's my html

```
<div class="w">
    <a href="#" class="d">1</a>
    <a href="#" class="d">2</a>
    <a href="#" class="d">3</a>
    <a href="#" class="d">4</a>
    <a href="#" class="d">5</a>
</div>
```

So the question is, Is that possible to make `.d` height equals by width of it?
I mean some thing like: `height: 14% OF WIDTH`.
I've read all units of css [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp), but I couldn't find anything useful

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2648733/make-a-div-square-when-there-is-a-dynamically-changing-width-based-on-percenta

Answer (score -2):

If you can't do it with javascript, and you can relate the width to the viewport, you can set width and height the same % of viewport width

```css
.w{
    width:80vw;
    display:block;
}

.d{
    width:11.2vw;
    display:inline-block;
    border:1px solid red;
    height:11.2vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="w">
    <a href="#" class="d">1</a>
    <a href="#" class="d">2</a>
    <a href="#" class="d">3</a>
    <a href="#" class="d">4</a>
    <a href="#" class="d">5</a>
</div>
```